# Retrieving posted data from ajax using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem retrieving the posted data from an ajax call, not sure what is wrong. The console output from the script below shows everything as expectred before the ajax call, but the data is not available in the connector

```
   function updateOptions(data){

        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.id);
        console.log(data.action);

        var data = {id: data.id, action : data.action};

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.connector.php?action=updateOptions',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            cache: false,
            dataType  : "json",

            success: function(data, status) {

                if(data.status == 'success'){

                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);

                }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                    console.log('selects not updated');
                }

            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log('an error has occurred');
            },

        });

    }
```

So the first 4 console.log entries show the data correctly, the first console.log in the success condition shows correctly. The second, shows:

```
Object {status: "success", msg: "Category added successfully", id: null, action: null, post: Array[0]}
```

the connector [more like a director]

```
   case 'updateOptions':
        error_log('Running updateOptions function ' . print_r($_POST, TRUE), 0);
        $output = $sbb->updateOptions($_POST);
        break;
```

Logs this:

```
Running updateOptions function Array\n(\n)\n,
```

if I try to echo $_POST['action'] or $_POST['data'] or something to the log I get an undefined index.

I am forcing the ajax call to return success in the class that the php case function is calling:

```
public function updateOptions($data){

        $output = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Category added successfully',
            'id' => $data['id'],
            'action' => $data['action'],
            'post' => $data,
        );

        return $output;

}
```

So the ajax call itself does work, it's the data that's not being passed.

Somehow I am not getting [or correctly retrieving] the data from the ajax post.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Sorry, maybe a bit misleading. I updated the question. it's the data that is not getting passed, I'm actually forcing a success condition to be returned to the ajax call.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: And does PHP automatically decode JSON? edit: nope, as Musa points out.

Comment: @slicedtoad, that's essentially what the error_log('Running updateOptions function ' . print_r($_POST, TRUE), 0); line is doing, outputting what ~should~ be the POST data array to the apache log.  no data, just an empty array!

Comment: Yup, but dump gives more info. But the issue is that you're posting a JSON string and php isn't expecting that as Musa's answer says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're posting JSON, $_POST is populated with key=value pairs, don't mix up JSON with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` (which is what php uses to populate `$_POST`.
To send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data with jQuery.ajax pass an object with the data as the data parameter

```
data: data, // removed JSON.stringify
```

Comment: ahhh, that makes life easier - I can actually do without var data = {id: data.id, action : data.action}; & just pass the data straight through. thanks!